# ubuntu CRON не запускается задача

Tags: ubuntu

записал в crontab -e две строки

```
* * * * * /home/docker/e.sh

44 9 * * * /home/docker/e1.sh
```

Оба скрипта с разрешением +x c одинаковым содержанием

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "WW $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" >> /home/docker/cron-test.txt
```

журнал дал такой вывод

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog

09:43:01 ans1 CRON[615513]: (docker) CMD (/home/docker/e.sh)
09:44:01 ans1 CRON[615573]: (docker) CMD (/home/docker/e.sh)
```

Текущий date Thu Jun  8 09:42:36 AM GMT 2023
timedatectl установлен в UTC 0, все времена одинаковые и указывают на 09:42:36

**Проблема:**

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не отработал Cron на второй строке с установленным временем 9:44 (каждый день) ?

Comment: Этот cron хоть как-то с docker'ом саязан? `все времена одинаковые и указывают на 09:42:36` -  что значит "все времена"?

Comment: cron запускается на хосте(не в контейнера) (ubuntu 22.04). на этом хосте docker установлен. timedatectl выдает одинаковые времена (в том смысле что UTC точно равно 0)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос я задал не корректно :)

Дело в том что строки в crontab у меня разделены вводом (пустой строкой)

Оказывается cron когда встречает пустую строку - так останавливает обработку других строк - поэтому нижняя строка не обрабатывалась.

Убрал пустую строку и все заработало